# Java Swing preview of a ODF word document

Tags: java, swing, odftoolkit

Does anyone know a way to embed an non-editable preview (like a print preview) of a odf writer document existing on the hard drive of the app host into a Java Swing GUI interface ?

Comment: Use http://www.jopendocument.org/ library.

Comment: Googling `opendocument odf java swing` will get you most any and all information that you would need. Note that this question is off topic as it is asking about 3rd party libraries.

Comment: jopendocument.org has a library which unfortunately only previews .ods documents (spreadhsheet files). @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: interestingly enough searching "Java Swing preview odf" returns this as first result, kind of a circle isn't it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple: the format ODF is a zip file with inside a folder Thumbnails with thumbnail.png.

With [java.util.zip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) no problem.

You can even try immediately with an URL `"jar:file:///... .odt!/Thumbnails/thumbnail.png"`. *Worked for me.* I am afraid such a thumbnail is optional though.

Comment: thank you! i just tried it but didn't find in the unzipped output the thumbnail unfortunately, seems you were right about saying it ain't a default file to have there

Comment: I tried it on Libre Office (under Linux), with a brand new document. Thanks, for the feedback; it seems not _that_ simple.

Comment: I actually found the thumbnail but it is such low res that I doubt it can be of any real use.

Comment: @sarah.ferguson yes too tiny; a text excerpt on base of content.xml is best.